# Recursive Algorithm - generate power numbers from prime factors

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I can't figure out a recursion for the following. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

given array of prime factors of the form [ (p1,k1)..] where p is a prime and k is its power, i want to find all the numbers below N which are of the form (p1^(a*k1))*p2^(b*k2) where a,b can be any constant.

Any ideas ?

edit::
Sorry if I was not clear. Its an array of N items, NOT 2. eg: [ 2, 3, 5, 7 ] whose product of any combination of integer powers is below 10000 => 2.3.3.5.5.7. or 2.2.2.2.2.3.5.7 and so on.

Comment: Why would you use a recursion for this? Sounds like two nested loops. (one for a, one for b).

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Its an array of N items, NOT 2. 
eg: [ 2, 3, 5, 7 ] whose product of any combination of integer powers is below 10000 => 2.3.3.5.5.7. or 2.2.2.2.2.3.5.7

Comment: In your first paragraph you state that you are given pairs of numbers but then in your example you just give a simple list, which is it?

Comment: Given a list of prime numbers, finding all +ve exponents of all these primes such that the product of the primes to their exponents is less than a constant C -> represented as p1^e1 * p2^e2 ... 

I hope its clear now.